# Recovering a Ripple wallet on Ledger Nano

Tags: ripple, wallet-recovery, ledger-hardware-wallet

I have 20 XRP in a Ledger Nano and before I load everything onto it I want to test the recovery procedure so I am prepared in case something goes wrong down the track

I have read the material [here](https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/ledger-nano-s-restoring-a-device-using-recovery-phrase-d80051ecf17a) on the Ledger documentation but it does not elaborate on how it recovers the keys for the apps you have installed - in this case XRP.

Ideally I would also like to generate my public and private keys as described [here](https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005297709-On-which-wallet-can-I-restore-my-wallet-if-I-lose-my-Ledger-device-) and store them somewhere safe - but again it does not elaborate on the keys for altcoins.

Thanks in advance on any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Ledger should recover all your funds including any altcoins like XRP from your 24-word recovery phrase. You may read technical details about the process in [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki).

I'm not sure whether there is an official Ledger tool for deriving keys for XPR from recovery phrase. You may use [Ian Coleman's BIP39 Mnemonic Code Converter](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/). It is possible to launch this site on the offline computer if you worry about keyloggers.

You may also find [this discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/7nit1z/ripple_xrp_wallet_recovery/) interesting.